# How to express total eradication of bacteria (inhibition zone) when placed into a table

Tags: microbiology

I am a grade 9 student studying the inhibition zones of several different essential oils by comparison to Tetracycline to prove there is merit to treatment of bacterial infection (investigation is being conducted evaluating efficacy against S. epidermidis). I am analysing it by measuring the efficacy of 100% essential oil, in addition to MIC and 10x MIC.

One of the essential oils totally eradicated the bacteria. How would I express that in a table?

Comment: Please specify in which method bacteria were eradicated.

Comment: It would probably help if you included a cell-phone picture of what you mean by "totally eradicated," and something that would not fit that description, for comparison.

Comment: The real piece of information that you need to supply is what measurement in what units is in the column in your table that you are worried about. If it is "diameter", as I believe is normal in this sort of semi-quantitative assay, what is your problem? Perhaps you are worried that the reader will not realize that 10cm (or whatever) is the diameter of your petri dish, and the limit of your ability to assay high doses. If this the case, perhaps the solution is not to use cm but % of total diameter, so complete eradication is 100%. (You might even use simple geometry to find % eradication.)

Comment: And, of course, there is the question whether you should be putting the results in a table or plotting them as a graph. That might make it obvious that you have reached a saturating dose of your magic potion.

Comment: Sorry I haven't been able to  respond, I've been super busy all week with World Scholars Cup... sadly, i dont have access to cell phone images as of now, however I can answer some of the other questions. The bacteria was inoculated onto a petri dish with agar. Then, right after the bacteria was introduced, 3 filter paper discs (that had been soaked in the essential oils) were introduced to the petri dish.

Comment: In terms of David's question, the problem i face is that there are multiple discs on each petri dish, meaning that i wouldn't be able to work out a percentage eradication? Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "totally eradicated"?  What did you actually see?  Are you saying (I'm guessing here) that all the bacteria in the dish died off, leaving you unable to tell which disc did it?  In that case, I'd say you should re-do your experiment.  If not, what was it?  (I suppose this difficulty in explaining to *us* what happened is proof that you do need a better way of explaining it in your paper!  Pity you can't send a picture!  I take it you can't send a sketch either?)

Comment: Ok, so by totally eradicated, I meant that there was no visible bacteria on the dish, while on my control dish (no antimicrobials) there was evident bacterial growth. Don't worry anymore, however, as I got a chance to consult with my teacher who provided me with a way of expressing this. Thanks for all the help!